# Lucene: exact matches aren't shown first

Tags: java, lucene, rank, scoring

I am using the demo IndexFiles and SearchFiles classes to index and search which are in org.apache.lucene.demo packet.

My issue is when I use a query that contains more than a word, I am not getting results that have the exact match. For instance:

```
Enter query:
"natural language"
Searching for: "natural language"
298 total matching documents
1. download\researchers.uq.edu.au\fields-of-research\natural-language-processing
.txt
2. download\researchers.uq.edu.au\research-project\16267.txt
3. download\researchers.uq.edu.au\research-project\16279.txt
4. download\researchers.uq.edu.au\research-project\18361.txt
5. download\www.uq.edu.au\news\%3Farticle%3D2187.txt
6. download\researchers.uq.edu.au\researcher\2115.txt
7. download\ceit.uq.edu.au\content\2013-2014-summer-research-scholarship-project
s-dr-alan-cody%3Fpage%3D1.txt
8. download\ceit.uq.edu.au\content\2013-2014-summer-research-scholarship-project
s-dr-alan-cody%3Fpage%3D2.txt
9. download\ceit.uq.edu.au\content\2013-2014-summer-research-scholarship-project
s-dr-alan-cody.txt
10. download\www.ceit.uq.edu.au\content\2013-2014-summer-research-scholarship-pr
ojects-dr-alan-cody.txt
Press (n)ext page, (q)uit or enter number to jump to a page.
```

does not have same results as:

```
Enter query:
natural language
Searching for: natural language
54307 total matching documents
1. download\cyberschool.library.uq.edu.au\display_resource.phtml%3Frid%3D190.txt

2. download\cyberschool.library.uq.edu.au\display_resource.phtml%3Frid%3D576.txt

3. download\cyberschool.library.uq.edu.au\display_resource.phtml%3Frid%3D46.txt
4. download\espace.library.uq.edu.au\view\UQ%3A166163.txt
5. download\cyberschool.library.uq.edu.au\display_resource.phtml%3Frid%3D108.txt

6. download\cyberschool.library.uq.edu.au\display_resource.phtml%3Frid%3D70.txt
7. download\cyberschool.library.uq.edu.au\display_resource.phtml%3Frid%3D708.txt

8. download\researchers.uq.edu.au\fields-of-research\natural-language-processing
.txt
9. download\researchers.uq.edu.au\research-project\16267.txt
10. download\cyberschool.library.uq.edu.au\display_resource.phtml%3Frid%3D117.tx
t
Press (n)ext page, (q)uit or enter number to jump to a page.
```

For instance the first matching document does not even contain "language" keyword.

If I use `explain()` method within `IndexSearcher` class then I am getting this result for 1st one:

```
1. download\cyberschool.library.uq.edu.au\display_resource.phtml%3Frid%3D190.txt
0.70643383 = (MATCH) sum of:
  0.5590494 = (MATCH) weight(contents:natural in 62541) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
    0.5590494 = score(doc=62541,freq=4.0 = termFreq=4.0
), product of:
      0.8091749 = queryWeight, product of:
        4.4216847 = idf(docFreq=13111, maxDocs=401502)
        0.18300149 = queryNorm
      0.6908882 = fieldWeight in 62541, product of:
        2.0 = tf(freq=4.0), with freq of:
          4.0 = termFreq=4.0
        4.4216847 = idf(docFreq=13111, maxDocs=401502)
        0.078125 = fieldNorm(doc=62541)
  0.1473844 = (MATCH) weight(contents:language in 62541) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
    0.1473844 = score(doc=62541,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0
), product of:
      0.5875679 = queryWeight, product of:
        3.2107275 = idf(docFreq=44012, maxDocs=401502)
        0.18300149 = queryNorm
      0.25083807 = fieldWeight in 62541, product of:
        1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
          1.0 = termFreq=1.0
        3.2107275 = idf(docFreq=44012, maxDocs=401502)
        0.078125 = fieldNorm(doc=62541)
```

If I click next and find a result such as this:

```
19. download\www.uq.edu.au\news\%3Farticle%3D2187.txt
0.47449595 = (MATCH) sum of:
  0.2795247 = (MATCH) weight(contents:natural in 35173) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
    0.2795247 = score(doc=35173,freq=4.0 = termFreq=4.0
), product of:
      0.8091749 = queryWeight, product of:
        4.4216847 = idf(docFreq=13111, maxDocs=401502)
        0.18300149 = queryNorm
      0.3454441 = fieldWeight in 35173, product of:
        2.0 = tf(freq=4.0), with freq of:
          4.0 = termFreq=4.0
        4.4216847 = idf(docFreq=13111, maxDocs=401502)
        0.0390625 = fieldNorm(doc=35173)
  0.19497125 = (MATCH) weight(contents:language in 35173) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
    0.19497125 = score(doc=35173,freq=7.0 = termFreq=7.0
), product of:
      0.5875679 = queryWeight, product of:
        3.2107275 = idf(docFreq=44012, maxDocs=401502)
        0.18300149 = queryNorm
      0.33182758 = fieldWeight in 35173, product of:
        2.6457512 = tf(freq=7.0), with freq of:
          7.0 = termFreq=7.0
        3.2107275 = idf(docFreq=44012, maxDocs=401502)
        0.0390625 = fieldNorm(doc=35173)
```

which page itself contains exact keyword "natural language". So my questions are:

1) Why Lucene does not show exact matches first?

2) Why Lucene shows a result that does not even contain a keyword?

3) Where/how can I change that so that it would first show exact matching ones and then more relevant ones?

Answer (score 0):

1 - It isn't intended to.  See the documentation on [Lucene query syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Terms).  The query `natural language` is a query made up of two terms.  On their own, Lucene has no preference for the terms be close together.  If you want to find exact matches, a phrase query is the correct approach, like `"natural language"`

2 - Both results in which you included an explaination do contain matches for both terms, see:

```
0.2795247 = (MATCH) weight(contents:natural in 35173) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
  0.2795247 = score(doc=35173,freq=4.0 = termFreq=4.0
...
0.19497125 = (MATCH) weight(contents:language in 35173) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
  0.19497125 = score(doc=35173,freq=7.0 = termFreq=7.0
```

According to Lucene, it found the term "natural" 4 times in that document, and "language" 7 times, in the content field (which I assume is your default field).

3 - Look over the query parser syntax, to see what makes the most sense to you.  It sounds like you might find [Proximity Searches](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Proximity_Searches) useful.

If you just want to simply get phrase matches followed by others, you could use something along the lines of:

```
"natural language" natural language
```

Comment: Thank you but `Proximity Search` would not actually find words separately. So that's not what I am after

Comment: Sure, which is why the other approach was provided, combining separate term queries with a phrase query, which should serve nicely.  Is that not adequate is some way?

Comment: I have already thought that actually but for larger queries let's say even for 4 keywords, I would have 3  queries that would consist of 2 worded, 2 queries that are 3 worded, and the query itself. I have developed an algorithm to find subqueries which takes O(n^3) time, so not that good if you consider a 10 keyword query.

I was wondering whether it is possible to combine Proximity Search with default search?

Comment: That's a somewhat different question that what you have asked here, and not really adequately described in the space of a comment, I don't think.  You might want to ask a new question in order to flesh this out a bit more.

Comment: Why is it different it still belongs to 3rd question I think? If I can combine Proximity Search with default search, I can boost the results from proximity search and that would give me higher scores, or am I wrong?