# Lucene multivalued field and numTerms

Tags: lucene

I am using lucene to index documents that have a multivalued text field named ‘city’.
Each document might have multiple values for this field, like la, los angeles etc.

Assuming

```
document d1 contains city = la ; city = los angeles
document d2 contains city = la mirada
document d3 contains city = la quinta
```

Now when I search for 'la', I would prefer getting d1 as it has the exact match ie., a match that doesn't have any extra terms than what is in the query. I read lucene already prefers documents with fewer terms as `DefaultSimilarity.computeNorm` does

`return state.getBoost() * ((float) (1.0 / Math.sqrt(numTerms)));`

The problem I have is, I am not sure how numTerms is calculated for a multivalued field like city. Here would numTerms for d1 be 1 or 3? Would the numTerms be the sum of all the numTerms for each field value?

Any idea on how to make the document d1 rank higher than d2 and d3?

Comment: Similar question answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217634/lucene-exact-matches-arent-shown-first

Comment: @mindas No, the question you are pointing to, though sounds similar, doesn't have anything to do with multivalued fields and how numTerms is computed.